# I can't deploy my Upgradeable contract using truffle plugins

Tags: erc-20, openzeppelin-contracts, contract-upgrading

I'm trying to deploy the following smart contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/ERC20Upgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";

contract MonstersOnTheWayUp is Initializable, ERC20Upgradeable {
    function initialize() initializer public {
        __ERC20_init("Promethium", "PRM");
    }
}
```

I'm using this script for migration:

```
// migrations/3_deploy_upgradeable_box.js
const { deployProxy } = require('@openzeppelin/truffle-upgrades');

const MonstersOnTheWayUp = artifacts.require("../contracts/MonstersOnTheWayUp");

module.exports = async function (deployer) {
  await deployProxy(MonstersOnTheWayUp, [""], { deployer, initializer: 'initialize' });
};
```

But when I try to run the command:

```
npx truffle deploy --reset --network rinkeby
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: The requested contract was not found. Make sure the source code is available for compilation
```

Why is this happening?
This is my project directory:[image]

Comment: Does this helps: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/how-to-verify-a-contract-on-etherscan-bscscan-polygonscan/14225 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const MonstersOnTheWayUp = artifacts.require('MonstersOnTheWayUp.sol');
```